# how to give WINE/ windows application access to privileged ports

Tags: wine

I'm trying to get a windows based game to run under WINE. The game itself needs access to ports 80 and 443.
I understand these are privileged ports, and a program needs root access to use them, but I obviously don't want to give wine root access.

I looked searched for a simplish answer, and it seems as if using either iptables or authbind is my best bet, but I can't find directions that I understand well enough to make work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
```

Then:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/bin/wine
```

And try your game.

Comment: Okay, just tried that, and still cannot connect to server. I also tried the same command on the application itself, as well as wineserve, and a couple of other .exe's in the programs directory.

Comment: So, just an update. I went through iptables and authbind commands. Nothing seemed to work. Then I made a new WINE prefix starting with wine version 1.7.17, and everything ran smooth. Apparently my game just don't play well with the older versions of wine.

Comment: so what worked ? iptables ? setcap ?